# How to set AssetSync.config.run_on_precompile when using Rails Initializer in configuring asset_sync gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

How do I set `AssetSync.config.run_on_precompile = false` when I'm using Rails Initializer to configure asset_sync gem in Rails 3?

When I run

```
bundle exec rake assets:clean --trace
```

I get an error that says:

```
** Invoke assets:clean:all (first_time)
** Invoke assets:cache:clean (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
undefined method `run_on_precompile=' for #
```

Answer (score 2):

I have also used assets_sync gem in my project recently and i didnt use `AssetSync.config.run_on_precompile = false` this is used in rake task.

If you want to set `run_on_precompile = false` you can set it to false in your `config/enviroments/production.rb` like this

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

For complete details on assets_sync implementation you can check this links

[assets_sync](https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync)

[heroku +assets_sync](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cdn-asset-host-rails31)

Still if any error persists then let me know

Comment: Yes, I'd like to disable it during a rake task. Thank you!

Comment: checkout this issue i dont think you can disable precompile [assets_sync](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview)